# showposts VS posts_per_page. showposts works perfect but deprecated!

Tags: wordpress

I'm unable to substitute posts_per_page with showposts in order to limit the number of posts returned in a list. When I use showposts, the resulting menu list is correctly displayed according to the number of posts I specify in the showposts limiter. However, when I use posts_per_page, the post limiter number appears to be irrelevant. The resulting list shows all posts, exceeding the limiter count.

Examples:

This works perfectly:

```
$myrecentposts = get_posts(array('post_not_in' => get_option('sticky_posts'), 'cat' => "-$cat,-$catHidden",'showposts' => $cb2_recent_count));
foreach($myrecentposts as  $idxrecent=>$post) {
```

However, when I sub in posts_per_page, this DOES NOT work...

```
$myrecentposts = get_posts(array('post_not_in' => get_option('sticky_posts'), 'cat' => "-$cat,-$catHidden",'posts_per_page' => $cb2_recent_count));
foreach($myrecentposts as  $idxrecent=>$post) {
```

*I'm only trying to get posts_per_page to work because I understand that showposts has been deprecated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`showposts` **is** deprecated. However, `posts_per_page` is for use with `query_posts()`, or more specifically, `WP_Query::query()`.

`numberposts` is the equivalent argument for `get_posts()`.

NOTE: I removed my original answer concerning incorrect handling of arguments inside `get_posts()`.

`posts_per_page` is not a valid argument for `get_posts()` for semantic reasons, since it suggests the idea of **pagination**, something which `get_posts()` does not support.

For clarity, and on behalf of @RichardM's comment, here's the skinny I originally wrote;

---

It's down to how `get_posts()` parses the arguments before passing them on to `WP_Query`.

I've cut it down to the real basics here;

```
function get_posts($args = null)
{
    $defaults = array('numberposts' => 5);
    $r = wp_parse_args($args, $defaults);

    if (!empty($r['numberposts']))
        $r['posts_per_page'] = $r['numberposts'];

    $get_posts = new WP_Query;
    return $get_posts->query($r);
}
```

See how `numberposts` overwrites `posts_per_page`, not accounting the condition that `posts_per_page` is being passed?

Comment: So I should replace showposts with numberposts? And numberposts is not on the endangered list I suppose :)

Comment: I think your original answer was useful, the edit seems to obscure the problem somewhat. As far as I'm aware there is nothing stopping you from using pagination with `get_posts`, other than it being semantically confusing.

Comment: I guess you **can** use pagination with `get_posts`, but it was never really designed for it - personally I feel `get_posts` should do what it says on the tin: just 'get posts'! If you want to get more fancy, roll onto `query_posts`.

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug :  http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/15150  it is fixed in 3.1