# WordPress pagination returns 1 post when it should return 10

Tags: php, custom-post-type, wordpress

I have 4 queries on my first page. Every section works perfect excepts portfolio section. I want to show 10 posts on my portfolio section but my query shows only one post.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'project-portfolio',
    'numberposts' => 10
    );
    $the_query = new WP_Query ($args);
if (have_posts()) : while ($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post();

wp_title();

endwhile; 
else:
endif; 
wp_reset_query();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe `numberposts` is a valid parameter for `WP_Query` (as it is not mentioned in the codex page for WP_Query), But I believe `posts_per_page` is what you're looking for.

According to the [Wordpress Codex WP_Query Page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

> posts_per_page (int) - number of post to show per page (available with Version 2.1, replaced showposts parameter). Use 'posts_per_page'=>-1 to show all posts (the 'offset' parameter is ignored with a -1 value). Set the 'paged' parameter if pagination is off after using this parameter. Note: if the query is in a feed, wordpress overwrites this parameter with the stored 'posts_per_rss' option. To reimpose the limit, try using the 'post_limits' filter, or filter 'pre_option_posts_per_rss' and return -1

So your `$args` array should be

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'project-portfolio',
    'posts_per_page' => 10
    );
```

**Edit**

The parameter `numberposts` is found in the [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) for `get_posts` where it states

> Note: 'numberposts' and 'posts_per_page' can be used interchangeably.

In the sentence following that it states

> For full parameters list see WP_Query.

However, the parameter `numberposts` is not found in the `WP_Query` codex.

**Edit**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3335128/2687861 states that `numberposts` is depreciated.